# Cant establish a connection to MySQL database using PHP

Tags: php, mysql, database

I created a database table using phpmyadmin and MySQL. Im trying to establish a connection to my database using a PHP script. Ive searched all alone and have found the right syntax and script to establish a simple connection. When i run the php file on my live server, the browser simply displays the actual code of the php file rather than a error message or any output.

Here is my php script that i am working with.

```
<?php

$username = "*******";
$password = "********";
$hostname = "*********"; 

//connection to the database
$dbhandle = mysql_connect($hostname, $username, $password) 
  or die("Unable to connect to MySQL");
echo "Connected to MySQL <br>";

?>
```

Any help or direction as to what might be causing me to have absolutely no output?

Comment: Please [stop using `mysql_*` functions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php). [These extensions](http://php.net/manual/en/migration70.removed-exts-sapis.php) have been removed in PHP 7. Learn about [prepared](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) statements for [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) and [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and consider using PDO, [it's really pretty easy](http://jayblanchard.net/demystifying_php_pdo.html).

Comment: Are you sure you have an apache server started?

Comment: get the *actual error with `or die(mysql_error())` . Or you can find the issues in your current error logs.

Comment: are you sure that the extension of the page is `.php`? also check whether your server has apache installed..

Comment: Yes i am sure i have .php file extension

Comment: in regards to the apache server, im not sure i have that started. How can i find that out?

Answer (score -1):

Because my duplicate flag was disputed despite this entire question being about PHP not rendering and the raw source being displayed instead I'm just going to quote @schmeeps' original answer. It's very thorough and covers a lot of the possible reasons PHP might not be being processed. If you found it useful, upvote the original answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5121589/6061978).

> Sounds like there is something wrong with your configuration, here's a
>   few things you can check:
>
> 1. Make sure that PHP is installed and running correctly. This may sound silly, but you never know. An easy way to check is to run `php
>      -v` from a command line and see if returns version information or any errors.
> 2. Make sure that the PHP module is listed **and uncommented** inside of your Apache's httpd.conf This should be something like `LoadModule
>      php5_module "c:/php/php5apache2_2.dll"` in the file. Search for
>      `LoadModule php`, and make sure that there is no comment (`;`) in
>      front of it.
> 3. Make sure that the http.conf file has the PHP MIME type in it. This should be something like `AddType application/x-httpd-php .php`. This
>      tells Apache to run `.php` files as PHP. Search for AddType, and then
>      make sure there is an entry for PHP, and that it is uncommented.
> 4. Make sure your file has the `.php` extension on it, or whichever extension specified in the MIME definition in point #3, otherwise it
>      will not be executed as PHP.
> 5. Make sure you are not using short tags in the PHP file (`<?`), these are <del>deprecated</del> *not enabled on all servers* by
>      default. Use `<?php` instead (or enable short tags in your php.ini
>      whith `short_open_tag=On` if you have code that relies on them).
> 6. Make sure you are accessing your file over your webserver using an URL like `http://localhost/file.php` not via local file access
>      `file://localhost/www/file.php`
>
> And lastly check the [PHP manual for further setup
>   tips](http://php.net/install).